# Can you extend an edge to make a loopcut?

Tags: loop

I would like to take these beveled edges and wrap them around the mesh as loopcuts (to remedy the large ngon created by bevelling).

Seeing that anytime you bevel something it creates a large ngon, there must be a way to do this to fix the topology. Otherwise, I can’t add any modifiers to smooth the edges (Bevel/Subsurf) because it looks awful.

[image: bevelled_edge]

John

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about your question, but maybe here is a way to fix your topology, does it give the results you want? By the way you don't so many edges to create a round corner.

[image]